# `Datomic.query.EntityMap` can return reverse entity reference. However, the behavior is out of my direct expectation. Is it a bug?

Tags: clojure, datomic

We can retrieve the reverse entity ref `:db/id` by using `datomic.api/touch` on `datomic.query.EntityMap`. However, after calling `seq` function, the `:db/id` key will disappear.

Consider my code like this:

```
(d/touch (first (get-allo-customers-by-user  (d/db conn)  [:user/email "aaa@example.com"])))
```

=> {:db/id 17592186045460, :customer/id 101, :customer/name "AAA"}

However strange things happen like this:

```
(seq (d/touch (first (get-allo-customers-by-user  (d/db conn)  [:user/email "aaa@example.com"]))))
```

=> ([:customer/id 101] [:customer/name "AAA"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably not a bug. Keep in mind that Datomic does not store an entity anywhere, all it stores are facts. The EntityMap representation contains a "fake" `:db/id`, but your data actually looks like this:

```
[17592186045460 :customer/id 101]
[17592186045460 :customer/name "AAA"]
```

So the fact that the id gets lost when you convert it into a seq seems like it could be unintended/random behavior, but not really a bug per se.

Note that you don't have to use `d/touch` to get a hold of the id - you can simply read the ID directly.

```
(def customer (first (get-allo-customers-by-user (d/db conn) [:user/email "aaa@example.com"])))
(:db/id customer)
```